# Count number of new and lost friends between two data frames in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-manipulation, network-analysis

I have two data frames of the same respondents, one from Time 1 and the next from Time 2. In each wave they nominated their friends, and I want to know:

1) how many friends are nominated in Time 2 but not in Time 1 (new friends)

2) how many friends are nominated in Time 1 but not in Time 2 (lost friends)

Sample data:

```
Time 1 DF

ID  friend_1  friend_2  friend_3  
1          4        12         7       
2          8         6         7   
3          9        NA        NA     
4         15         7         2    
5          2        20         7   
6         19        13         9       
7         12        20         8    
8          3        17        10 
9          1        15        19     
10         2        16        11  


Time 2 DF

ID  friend_1  friend_2  friend_3  
1          4        12         3    
2          8         6        14       
3          9        NA        NA      
4         15         7         2      
5          1        17         9
6          9        19        NA
7         NA        NA        NA     
8          7         1        16  
9         NA        10        12   
10         7        11         9
```

So the desired DF would include these columns (EDIT filled in columns):

```
ID  num_newfriends  num_lostfriends  
1               1                 1      
2               1                 1   
3               0                 0      
4               0                 0        
5               3                 3          
6               0                 1  
7               0                 3   
8               3                 3
9               2                 3
10              2                 1
```

EDIT2:

I've tried doing an anti join

```
df3 <- anti_join(df1, df2)
```

But this method doesn't take into account friend id numbers that might appear in a different column in time 2 (For example respondent #6 friend 9 and 19 are in T1 and T2 but in different columns in each time)

Comment: Can you give an example for the output, e.g. for ID 1?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(
  gather(df1, key, x, -ID),
  gather(df2, key, y, -ID),
  by = c("ID", "key")
) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(
    num_newfriends = sum(!y[!is.na(y)] %in% x[!is.na(x)]),
    num_lostfriends = sum(!x[!is.na(x)] %in% y[!is.na(y)])
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID num_newfriends num_lostfriends
   <int>          <int>           <int>
 1     1              1               1
 2     2              1               1
 3     3              0               0
 4     4              0               0
 5     5              3               3
 6     6              0               1
 7     7              0               3
 8     8              3               3
 9     9              2               3
10    10              2               2
```

Comment: I ran this but the output was just one row, it didn't give results for each respondent.

Comment: Hum, not sure what this could be. Do you get any error?

Comment: Nope no error! It just gave me 1 for newfriends and 3 for lostfriends.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help you unless you'd provide us with a `dput` of your actual data, otherwise I cannot reproduce - it works on your example for me.

Comment: Unfortunately it's restricted data so I can't share. I'll see if I can get it working. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you grouped by the ID column (or whatever it's called in your actual table)? I would expect one row if you summarized everything without grouping.

Comment: Yes I am grouping by the ID column, it still is only giving me one row.

Answer (score 1):

Simple comparisons would be an option

```
library(tidyverse)
na_sums_old <- rowSums(is.na(time1))
na_sums_new <- rowSums(is.na(time2))
kept_friends <- map_dbl(seq(nrow(time1)), ~ sum(time1[.x, -1] %in% time2[.x, -1]))
kept_friends <- kept_friends - na_sums_old * (na_sums_new >= 1)

new_friends  <- 3 - na_sums_new - kept_friends
lost_friends <- 3 - na_sums_old - kept_friends

tibble(ID = time1$ID, new_friends = new_friends, lost_friends = lost_friends)


# A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID new_friends lost_friends
   <int>       <dbl>        <dbl>
 1     1           1            1
 2     2           1            1
 3     3           0            0
 4     4           0            0
 5     5           3            3
 6     6           0            1
 7     7           0            3
 8     8           3            3
 9     9           2            3
10    10           2            2
```

Comment: This seemed to work, but in the full data set some of the values end up being negative, any idea why? The full dataset has up to 7 friends, so i replaced 3 - with 7 -

Answer (score 1):

You can make `anti_join` work by first pivoting to a "long" data frame.

```r
df1 <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("friend_"), values_to = "friend") %>%
  drop_na()
df2 <- df2 %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("friend_"), values_to = "friend") %>%
  drop_na()

head(df1)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>      ID name     friend
#>   <int> <chr>     <int>
#> 1     1 friend_1      4
#> 2     1 friend_2     12
#> 3     1 friend_3      7
#> 4     2 friend_1      8
#> 5     2 friend_2      6
#> 6     2 friend_3      7

lost_friends <- anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "friend"))
new_fiends <- anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("ID", "friend"))

respondents <- distinct(df1, ID)

respondents %>%
  full_join(
    count(lost_friends, ID, name = "num_lost_friends")
  ) %>%
  full_join(
    count(new_fiends, ID, name = "num_new_friends")
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("num_")), replace_na, 0)
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       ID num_lost_friends num_new_friends
#>    <int>            <dbl>           <dbl>
#>  1     1                1               1
#>  2     2                1               1
#>  3     3                0               0
#>  4     4                0               0
#>  5     5                3               3
#>  6     6                1               0
#>  7     7                3               0
#>  8     8                3               3
#>  9     9                3               2
#> 10    10                2               2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>